# Logstash Elasticsearch Output Bulk Insert Conflicts With Elasticsearch Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm having an issue where it appears that my log data and workflow is conflicting with how the Elasticsearch output bulk inserts.

What I am trying to do is use the Elasticsearch filter plugin to do a lookup to find the start event when I receive an end event. However, the issue is that the events are often next to each other or very close (within a couple lines). When the Elasticsearch filter lookup is performed it will not find the corresponding start event because it has not yet been sent to Elasticsearch because of how the output bulk inserts.

For reference, the workflow is as follows:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
  if [eventType] == "End" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      user => "logstash-es"
      password => "****"
      index => "logstash-*"
      query_template => "config/logstash-query.json"
      fields => [["event-data", "start-event-data"]]
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "[localhost:9200]"
    user => "logstash-es"
    password => "****"
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

How can I force the Elasticsearch output to send events individually so that the Elasticsearch filter lookup will succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found my answer. When starting Logstash you can set the batch size with the following flag, -b, --pipline.batch.size which can be set to 1.

Ex:

```
.\bin\logstash.bat -f path/to/config.conf -b 1
```

I am coupling this with the following flags as well, -w, --pipeline.workers to set it to 1 worker so that events are not processed out of order and -u, --pipeline.batch.delay to increase the delay between creating batches.